# how to query single product in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to query a single product. And I searched it to google on how to do it and a found this code.

```
do_shortcode('[product_page id="{$product_id}"]');
```

but this dispaly the whole content of products. All I want is just an image,description and the price. How can I do this using WP_QUERY()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `Wp_Query` for selecting the single product from the database you have to pass the `p` in the `$args` so that if fetches the data and the `post_type` should be as `product`.

> Follow up the Normal `$args` method along with that you have to add the following lines of code.

```
<?php
$params = array(
 'p' => 'YOUR PRODUCT ID', id of a page, post, or custom type
 'post_type' => 'product'
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :  ?>
<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post();  ?>
<?php the_title();  ?>
<?php the_content();  ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'No Product' );  ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm new in wordpress. I dont have enough knowledge on it.

Comment: Its my pleasure helping you. Happy coding:)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the shortcode that provides *WooCommerce* by default?
I think is more practical than create another separated code or function to do the same stuff.

```
[product id="99"]
```

> Check out it here : [Shortcodes included with WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-8)

Well, with a variable, you can try this in your template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_page id='.$product_id.']'); ?>
```

Comment: he is asking about wp_query code...